# the most efficient way to check if an integer can be divided by a float number in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point, integer

Wondering what is the most efficient way to check if an integer can or cannot be divided by another number (could be float) in Python 2.7. Or more general, what is the most efficient way to check if an integer can be divided by n (n could be a float number) in Python 2.7.

My pain point is, if I try to get `x/n`, it is always an integer.

Comment: is `x % n == 0` not applicable here?

Comment: @StephenRauch, maybe it is my issue not state my question very clear, I want to handle situation when n is a float number. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi Moinuddin, I clarified my question.

Comment: @LinMa as floats are not accurate enough for this task, I would recommend you to use [fractions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html). `1%0.2` -> `0.199..` and `1%Fraction(1,5)` -> `Fraction(0,1)`

Comment: @ovs, thanks! Will try, do you think the solution posted by abccd will work? That solution seems much simpler than fraction?

Comment: It will work for his example, but only for floats like '.125, .5, .75'

Comment: It won't work for floats like `0.1` and `0.2` as they can't be represented in binary

Comment: Thanks @ovs, but in your solution, why you check only for `Fraction(0,1)`, I think as long as numerator is `0`, it is ok, why do you care denominator  must be `1`?

Comment: `Fraction(0, 1)` is what was returned. You can just check by `==0`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if x % n == 0 :
```

hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks Jay, maybe it is my issue not state my question very clear, I want to handle situation when n is a float number. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
x = 25
y = 2.5 # Or something
if not x % y: # Works with float too
    print 'can divide'
else:
    print 'cannot divide'
```

Comment: Thanks abccd, maybe it is my issue not state my question very clear, I want to handle situation when n is a float number. Any thoughts?

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure if your method will have issue because Python floating point calculation is not 100% accurate, suppose X can be divided by Y (Y is a float number), but Python gets a result which is a fraction other than an integer (because of Python floating calculation approximate itself)?